# Direct3d Color space conversion in GPU

Tags: video, ffmpeg, directx, rendering, direct3d

Creating direct3d surface inYV12 format and rendering video frames in yuv420 format causes a blur video. Seems like there is a smog on video. I think this is because yuv 420 color space format's data range is in 16-235 for Y planes and 16-240 for U and V planes. They are not in range of 0-255.

I changed color format to BGRA in CPU by using ffmpeg's sws_scale() function and I created direct3d surface in BGRA format and then displayed video is OK. But cpu consumption is very high due to color space conversion. Is there any way to make color conversion in GPU or is there another way to have sharp video display?

This is how I create YV12 surface

```
m_pDirect3DDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(_srcWidth, _srcHeight, (D3DFORMAT)MAKEFOURCC('Y', 'V', '1', '2'), D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &m_pDirect3DSurfaceRender, NULL);
```

Here I copy yuv planes of camera's video frames data to direct3d surface

```cpp
        BYTE* pict = (BYTE*)d3d_rect.pBits;
        BYTE* Y = pY;
        BYTE* V = pV;
        BYTE* U = pU;

        for (int y = 0; y < _srcHeight; y++)
        {
            memcpy(pict, Y, p1);
            pict += d3d_rect.Pitch;
            Y += p1;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < _srcHeight >> 1; y++)
        {
            memcpy(pict, V, p3);
            pict += d3d_rect.Pitch >> 1;
            V += p3;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < _srcHeight >> 1; y++)
        {
            memcpy(pict, U, p2);
            pict += d3d_rect.Pitch >> 1;
            U += p2;
        }
```

I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Those ranges are normal and should not cause any problems. If you are getting a blurred video then there is a problem in your code that you didn't post here. It is possible to convert colorspace on GPU.

Comment: You might try using DXVA to convert from YUV to RGB in GPU: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/dxva-video-processing. More specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/dxva-video-processing#video-process-blit. DirectX 11 counterpart can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11videocontext-videoprocessorblt

Comment: I was always converting every frame format to YUV420 even its format was already YUV420. And this conversion in CPU using ffmpeg  was causing a video like smog on it. I render YUV420 frames directly to YV12 direct3d surface and everything is OK now. Thank you